# unzipping and re-zipping a file results in a different hash

Tags: linux, zip, hashing, unzip

I have an ev3 file called robot.ev3, when I ran `file` on it, the output I got was `robot.ev3: Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract`, I unzipped the file using `unzip robot.ev3 -d robot` moved into `robot` and zipped the file using `zip -r ../robotx.ev3 *`

when I ran `md5sum robot.ev3 robotx.ev3` the output I got was:

```
31bf1fb8767707cd476c425ab7cf2a5a robot.ev3
7298c1ec0467672cf5e210f945261ae2 robotx.ev3
```

I tried the same process with a file I created instead of a file created by `LEGO MINDSTORMS EV3 Home Edition` and the hashes were the same.

Why are the hashes of the ev3 files different?

Comment: Probably one of the file attributes like atime. if you zip to robotx.ev3 and roboty.ev3 those should be the same

Comment: I don't think that's the case, I hexdumped the files and they were completely different except for the beginning.

Comment: The ZIP file format allows different compression levels and even different algorithms to be used. So it's perfectly fine to have different hashes and file contents depending on the parameters used to generate the file.

Answer (score 2):

Because the ZIP file contains the file name. So if you change the name of the zipped files this changes the data in the ZIP, and therefore the hash of the ZIP file.

Example: create a sample file

```
>>>echo "
> 
> Because the ZIP file contains the file name. So if you change the name of the zipped files this changes the data in the ZIP, and therefore the hash of the ZIP file.
> " >data1.txt
```

Copy files, keep timestamps (for ZIP, only the modification time counts)

```
>>>cp -p data1.txt data2.txt
```

Check that we have identical files

```
>>>ll data*.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 me me 168 May 17 15:27 data1.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 me me 168 May 17 15:27 data2.txt
>>>md5sum data*.txt
bf9c51a337186ff5c144177de7f84c00  data1.txt
bf9c51a337186ff5c144177de7f84c00  data2.txt
```

Create the ZIP

```
>>>zip data1.zip data1.txt
updating: data1.txt (deflated 34%)
>>>zip data2.zip data2.txt
updating: data2.txt (deflated 34%)
```

ZIPs are different

```
>>>md5sum data*.zip
50eb0d7a660833169b9856bd6eab5011  data1.zip
e16d9e4ae07aa521857552eaec6610b5  data2.zip
```

A contrario, zipping the very same file twice to two different ZIPs creates identical ZIPs with the same hash:

```
>>>zip data1B.zip data1.txt
updating: data1.txt (deflated 34%)
>>>md5sum data1*.zip
50eb0d7a660833169b9856bd6eab5011  data1B.zip
50eb0d7a660833169b9856bd6eab5011  data1.zip
```

To compare ZIPs, it's best to uncompress them, unless you use something that mounts them as a device. I spent some time comparing EARs in a former life (EARs are ZIPs of WARs, that themselves are ZIPs of JARs, that themselves are ZIP of .class java files).